How can I prevent index.d.ts from showing when I command-click on my custom react component in VSCode
I am having an issue when I want to view a react component's definition and occurrences in my create-react-app project in VSCode. It keeps showing the index.d.ts file (node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts) has the first option. The file links to this:
        (
            props: P,
            /**
             * @deprecated
             *
             * @see {@link https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#referencing-context-in-lifecycle-methods React Docs}
             */
            deprecatedLegacyContext?: any,
        ): ReactElement<any, any> | null;

How can I prevent this file from showing when I command-click on my custom react component?
